# Проект по проверке олимпиад

Tags: java, c#, c++, python, c

Стоит такая задача. Есть сайт с олимпиадой по программированию и нужно сделать автопроверку решения олимпиады. Т.е. участник отправляет файл с кодом(C#, C++, C, Java, Python, Pascal) на сервер и на сервере запускается этот код с входными данными и сверяется с выходными. Организовать работу сервера - проблем нет. Подскажите идеи, как реализовать саму проверку файлов с кодом на всех языках. Входные и выходные данные будут записаны в файлы. Можете предлагать для отдельных языков. Была идея реализовать все через терминал, но зашел в тупик. Может кто-то знает, как именно можно через терминал все сделать.

Comment: Отличный вопрос! Как мне кажется, основная проблема даже не в проверке кода, а в реализации защиты машины, на которой этот код исполняется.

Comment: Файлы с кодом не проверяются, проверяется выхлоп приложений, собранных из них. Сборка и запуск этих приложений естественно производится в песочнице.

Comment: @VTT Легко сказать "в песочнице". Вот тут мне очень интересна как раз реализация :). Что Вы имели в виду? Поясните, пожалуйста, если Вам не трудно.

Comment: @VVT объясните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: @nomnoms12 Ну вот например готовое опенсорсное решение https://github.com/remoteinterview/compilebox

Comment: @VVT кажется я понял. Создать контейнеры для каждого языка в Докере, ограничить их по ресурсам. Запускать код в контейнере и потом сверять полученный результат в результате запуска кода ?

Comment: Не совсем, конечно, ответ по теме, но возможно вы не захотите изобретать велосипед, узнав, что такие системы уже сделаны и есть в общем доступе. Их целый список. Ejudge должен бы вас устроить